# Why isn't the logic to change my value working?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a text RPG, and I was just screwing around, testing out how I'd do the XP system. I tried to make it where when the Player's XP is greater than or equal to the needed XP, then it subtracts them and levels up the player. I can't figure out what I did wrong. (The problem I'm having is that the `PlayerXP` goes straight past the needed XP)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
  <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    setInterval(function() {
      Player.Stats.XP++;
      document.getElementById('PlayerLevel').innerHTML = Player.Stats.Level;
      document.getElementById('PlayerXP').innerHTML = Player.Stats.XP
      document.getElementById('PlayerNeededXP').innerHTML = Player.Stats.NeededXP;
    }, 1000);
  </script>
  <p>Level: <span id='PlayerLevel'></span></p>
  <p>Experience: <span id='PlayerXP'></span> - <span id='PlayerNeededXP'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
NeededEXP = [
  /**/,
  25,    //1
  50,    //2
  100,   //3
  200,   //4
  500,   //5
  1000,  //6
  1750,  //7
  3000,  //8
  5000,  //9
  10000  //10

];

var Player = new Object();

Player.Stats = new Object();
Player.Stats.Level = 1;
Player.Stats.XP = 0;
Player.Stats.NeededXP = NeededEXP[Player.Stats.Level];

if(Player.Stats.XP >= Player.Stats.NeededXP) {
  Player.Stats.XP = Player.Stats.NeededXP - Player.Stats.XP;
  Player.Stats.Level++;
}
```

Comment: Where in the interval is the if statement checked?

Comment: You need to edit that title (how many people start off that way) plus I'd recommend posting "No frameworks" at the bottom of your question so no tries to hijack it with unrelated code.

Comment: As hinted in a previous comment, you do the `if(Player.Stats.XP >= Player.Stats.NeededXP)` exactly once, and then never do it again. You need to run that logic every time you change the XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check the current XP value at every iteration of the timeout:

```js
NeededEXP = [
  25, //1
  50, //2
  100, //3
  200, //4
  500, //5
  1000, //6
  1750, //7
  3000, //8
  5000, //9
  10000 //10
];

var Player = {};
Player.Stats = {};
Player.Stats.Level = 1;
Player.Stats.XP = 0;
Player.Stats.NeededXP = NeededEXP[Player.Stats.Level];

setInterval(function() {
  Player.Stats.XP++;

  if (Player.Stats.XP >= Player.Stats.NeededXP) {
    Player.Stats.XP -= Player.Stats.NeededXP;
    Player.Stats.Level++;
    Player.Stats.NeededXP = NeededEXP[Player.Stats.Level];
  }

  document.getElementById('PlayerLevel').innerHTML = Player.Stats.Level;
  document.getElementById('PlayerXP').innerHTML = Player.Stats.XP
  document.getElementById('PlayerNeededXP').innerHTML = Player.Stats.NeededXP;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p>Level: <span id='PlayerLevel'></span>
</p>
<p>Experience: <span id='PlayerXP'></span> - <span id='PlayerNeededXP'></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Ohh, i'm not the greatest at this, but thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

You cut and paste check snippet in setInterval function block like this

```
setInterval(function() {
  Player.Stats.XP++;

  if(Player.Stats.XP >= Player.Stats.NeededXP) {
    Player.Stats.XP = Player.Stats.NeededXP - Player.Stats.XP;
    Player.Stats.Level++;
  }

  document.getElementById('PlayerLevel').innerHTML = Player.Stats.Level;
  document.getElementById('PlayerXP').innerHTML = Player.Stats.XP
  document.getElementById('PlayerNeededXP').innerHTML = Player.Stats.NeededXP;
}, 1000);
```